# media-query for iPad Air: at 1536px, how to differentiate from PCs?

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

I'm developing a page with RWD. Due to limited budget, I can only manage two cases: mobile (meaning phone or tablet) and PC (Win or Mac).

Basically, I'm setting an hard-limit at 1280px (the old, 4:3 PC monitor): if the client resolution is lower, go for mobile media-query. If it's greater, go for PC (of course it could be a mobile "full HD" (1920px) display on landscape, but I'm ok giving them the PC version).

The "problem" is with iPad Air in portrait: the thing resolution is 1536px, so it would get the PC version! Since I'm ok with PC version to HD phones on landscape, should I accept this too or this even higher resolution would degrade the experience below the point of usability?

Comment: it would be helpful to see your current media queries. Next to max/min-width, you may also check `device-width/height` and `min/max-resolution`. Also what is your question? "*should I accept this too...*" This strongly depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
[it turns out that iPad viewport is fixed at 1024px](http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=ipad) so if I target 1025px as non-mobile resolution, everything is fine!